# send "spacebar key" using SendKeys.sendwait()

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

I was wondering how to send `spacebar key` using   **SendKeys.send();**
It works with the other keys but only the spacebar !!
Here is the link where I found the other keys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

Answer (score 38):

Per the documentation you linked, `SendKeys.send(" ");` will send a space key.

The only keys which require special codes are "characters that aren't displayed when you press a key".

Answer (score 0):

A normal space with double quotes works `SendKeys.SendWait(" ")`

...but if you are sending characters as `Char` instead of `String` as the arguments make sure to replace the `Char` space with a `String` space.

```
if (chr == ' ')
{
    SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
}else{
    SendKeys.SendWait("{"+chr+"}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From VBScript on Windows, you can open the system menu of the active window like this (the forum proposes 4 languages to be put as title, js was the nearest) :

```js
oShell.SendKeys "%{ }", true
oShell.SendKeys "~", true
```

Answer (score -8):

Use application.sendkeys "{SPACE}"

Comment: `"{SPACE}"` is not one of the keywords for the `SendKeys.SendWait()` method.