# Sending ctrl-space with SendKeys in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I'm doing some basic automation type stuff and I need to send ctrl-space to the desktop (I need to make sure that nothing is selected so that when I do `SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}");` I get the generic desktop menu, not the one for any specific file). I've tried the obvious things (actual space character, "SPACEBAR", "SPACE") and none of them work, they all give me a n ArgumentException. Anybody know the right way to do this?

C# on .NET 4.0 and Windows 7, if any of that makes a difference.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153394/send-spacebar-key-using-sendkeys-sendwait

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

I think what you are after is

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^( )");
```